# CSS Important when reloading page

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have custom css for my nav buttons. On pressing buttons the page ofcourse reloads and I can for a split second see the original btn colors. Worse if one of my buttons does a "target=_blank" then button that was selected prior to it remains on the original bootstrap colors..

Would appreciate insights how to fully override the css so I always get the custom colors

Regards

M.R.

Comment: Hi Meir. This is hard to help without having more information about the issue, like html/css/javascript. How are you setting the selected, are you adding a class on the nav item with javascript or during render for instance?

Comment: Hi
I am using cshtml.. I load a custom css file based on a ViewBag value.I've tried loading the css file before the <Link theme bootstrap but still same thing..

Comment: are you loading your css in header? Just out of curiosity why load the css for your site navigation through the ViewBag? I get the custom part just navigation seems to be vital for your site and would not be "custom loaded", like it follows along on all pages I assume.

Comment: Yes the css is being loaind in <head> and No the navigation options and the navbar colors change based on the path of the site.

Comment: If you put that css in a file and have that load as a static reference (as your other css), does that help?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use grunt to generate inline css and that would solve the problem.
If you are unable to configure the grunt then add button styles in inline.

Comment: Hi I am using cshtml.. I load a custom css file based on a ViewBag value.I've tried loading the css file before the <Link theme bootstrap but still same thing.

Comment: you can see how it works on this website : https://www.ctp.co.il/Dashboard/synctest

select Multitabs.. then hit the "Home" icon

Comment: The problem I see is it take some time to load the css files. that's why it shows the original colors. Just add your colors in inline styles.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your site link. Your request takes too long so the css is not there. Just have that css load when your page does. There is no reason to keep a 1kb file to be loaded on request, or any size at all. What is your reason to have this approach?

Comment: Thanks for your response.. Can you elaborate on "load the css when page does" instead of on request?

Comment: @MeirRotfleisch You have css on your initial pageload, for example your bootstrap, because your site has styling when it loads. So instead of loading your css when your request is done, you load it at the same time as your other css. Does it make sense?

Comment: ,,, thanks.. actually this site wasn't originally done by me .. its mvc which im not that great at.. Think you are able to help me with overcoming this for payment?

Comment: @MeirRotfleisch I wouldn't feel good taking any money for it, plus I'm also quite busy these days :). I think we as a community can help you with no problem. If you update the question and add .NET tag, or start a new one with how your implementation with the css, and your ajax request it will be solved. The way I see it, it is "just" to change so you have a referens to your custom css in the header instead of loading it and populating it by request.